# hangman graphics blank word creation and space removal

Tags: python

```
graphics=['''------------
             |         |        ''','''
------------
|         |  ''','''

------------
|         |         
|          O''','''
------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / |''','''
------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / | 
|          | ''','''
------------
|         |
|          O 
|         / |
|          |
|         / | 
|
|            ''']

print('Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!')



while True:
    words=['table','chair','pencil','stapler','pen',
          'computer','printer','cable','books','shelf']

    alphabet=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g,','h','i','j','k','l',
             'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

    number=input('Please enter an integer number 
    (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list:')    

    if number=='':
        print('Empty input!')
        continue
    elif number in alphabet:
        print('Input must be an integer!')
        continue

    number=int(number)

    if number<0 or number>9:
        print('Index is out of range!')
        continue

    elif 0<=number<10:
        break

words2=[]
words2.extend(words[number])


print('The length of the word is: ',len(words2))
print('')

i=0
j=0
x=0
while j<6 and i!=len(words2):

    letter=input('Please enter the letter you guess: ')

    for alphabet in letter:
        if alphabet in words2:
            print('The letter is in the word.')
            i=i+1

            if i==len(words2):
                    print('You have found the mystery word. You win!')
                    print('Goodbye!')
                    break
            else:
                continue       

        elif alphabet not in words2:
            if letter not in alphabet:
                print('You need to input a single alphabetic character!')
            elif letter not in words2:
                j=j+1
                print('The letter is not in the word.')
                print(graphics[j])
```

Hi! This is a hangman game I am almost done with. I just have 2 questions.

1- There is a line space between graphic and printed line.
For example->

The letter is not in the word.

---

|         |

How can I remove this gap?

2- I wanted to create a blank word made of'*' in equal to length of the word and in which the 'correct' letters get substituted with '*' in the right place. I was confused about how to do that. 
I know that list replace function is to be used but how would I create a blank word in the first place?

YOU DONT HAVE TO GIVE ME THE ANSWER if it is something I should figure out or complicated. Just point me in the right direction.

THANKS! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
graphics=['''------------
             |         |        ''','''
------------
|         |  ''','''

------------
|         |         
|          O''','''
------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / |''','''
------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / | 
|          | ''','''
------------
|         |
|          O 
|         / |
|          |
|         / | 
|
|            ''']
```

Each string in `graphics` starts with a newline.

The newline in the string plus the implicit newline gives you a blank line between the text and the graphics.

Reformat your string to make the `-----` start on the same line as the `'''` to remove the extra line break